# how to display a csv string in UI like a table?

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

I am new in dealing with this, so probably this is trival task, but let me know if this question isnt necessary, I will cancel it.

In my front end, I have a api that will return my a string which is supposed to be a csv xlsc, after I call a api.

After that, I would like to show it on UI.

**Problem in it**

This is the example string I get from the response

```
'key,Asset Class,Benchmark Name,Benchmark Source
\r\n1001,Macro,US CSA,BLOOMBERG
\r\n1026,Equity,MSCI x USD,BLOOMBERG
\r\n1002,Equity,MSCI  USD,BLOOMBERG\r\n'
```

There are 4 header, and there are 4 row of data
As you can see, this is not something I could display it in table. I would like to ask how could I frame this data structure, so that it could be listed out. or at least like a table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the other answer, the most intuitive way is by splitting the string. I made an react approach to this.

```js
let data =
  "key,Asset Class,Benchmark Name,Benchmark Source \r\n1001,Macro,US CSA,BLOOMBERG \r\n1026,Equity,MSCI x USD,BLOOMBERG \r\n1002,Equity,MSCI  USD,BLOOMBERG\r\n";

data = data.slice(0, -2); // gets rid of the last "\r\n"
const rows = data.split(" \r\n").map((cols) => cols.split(","));

const Table = () => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((cols, index) => (
          <tr key={`row-${index}`}>
            {cols.map((value) => (
              <td key={value}>{value}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

function App() {
  return <Table />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks ! could you also vote up this topic, so this could also be seen by others?

Comment: I see below error when I paste it on react ide, May i see your code in running ? 
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): %s cannot appear as a child of <%s>.%s%s%s
<tr>
table
 Add a <tbody>, <thead> or <tfoot> to your code to match the DOM tree generated by the browser.

Comment: That is my mistake, you should surround the `{rows.map(....` with a `<tbody>` tag

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way is split string by line break for each row and by delimiter for each column then loop over it to create a table

here is a rendering in vanilla but it should also share the same idea with react

see a sample fiddler here

```html
<div id="root">
  <table>
    <tbody id="tt"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
var f = `key,Asset Class,Benchmark Name,Benchmark Source
\r\n1001,Macro,US CSA,BLOOMBERG
\r\n1026,Equity,MSCI x USD,BLOOMBERG
\r\n1002,Equity,MSCI  USD,BLOOMBERG\r\n`.split('\n\r')

const tt = document.getElementById('tt')

for (let line of f) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tt.appendChild(tr)
    for (let col of line.split(',')) {
      const td = document.createElement('td')
      td.innerText = col;
      tr.appendChild(td)
  }
}
```